# PHP Images display

Tags: php, image

I have this script:

```
 <?php 
                $count = 0;
        foreach(glob("images/{*.gif,*.jpg,*.png,*.jpeg,*.bmp}", GLOB_BRACE) as $image)
        while ($image)
        {
            if($count==3)
            {
               print "</tr>";
               $count = 0;
            }
            if($count==0)
               print "<tr>";
               print "<td>";
            ?>
               <img src="<?php echo $image;?>" width="80" height="80"/>
                <?php
            $count++;
            print "</td>";
        }
        if($count>0)
           print "</tr>";
        ?>
```

It supposed to take the images from a folder ("images" in this case) and display them 3 on a row. But it displays one picture 1000000 times. What cand I do to fix this? I tried to fix it, all I know is that the problem is at the "while" line.

Comment: I think you do not need `while($image)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the line

```
while($image)
```

Note that the line

```
foreach(glob("images/{*.gif,*.jpg,*.png,*.jpeg,*.bmp}", GLOB_BRACE) as $image)
```

is already looping along the images and will finish when there are no more in the directory.

I cleaned the code a little bit:

```
<?php 
    $count = 0;
    foreach(glob("images/{*.gif,*.jpg,*.png,*.jpeg,*.bmp}", GLOB_BRACE) as $image)
    {
        if($count==3)
        {
           print "</tr>";
           $count = 0;
        }
        if($count==0)
           print "<tr>";

        print "<td>";
        print "<img src=$image width=\"80\" height=\"80\"/>";
        print "</td>";
        $count++;
    }
    print "</tr>";
?>
```

Comment: I tried this, but it will show all of them on one row, not 3 on a row.

Comment: @sergiu Because you have not wrapped your code in brackets thus the `foreach` only applies to the first line and `$count` is never incremented.

Comment: Exactly. @Sergiu, I have cleaned the code a little bit so everything has more sense. Sometimes the way we ident code helps a lot!

Comment: Good to read that. Then, you could mark @GeorgeReith answer or mine as accepted, as I think both can work!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `$image` doesn't change during the while loop. Thus you create an infinite loop inside your `foreach` because `$image` continues to evaluate to true.

The while loop is unnecessary in your code and can be removed. You already loop over the images using your `foreach` statement.

Make sure to wrap all your `foreach` logic in curly braces like so:

```
foreach(glob("images/{*.gif,*.jpg,*.png,*.jpeg,*.bmp}", GLOB_BRACE) as $image)
{
    if($count==3)
    {
       print "</tr>";
       $count = 0;
    }
    if($count==0)
       print "<tr>";
       print "<td>";
    ?>
       <img src="<?php echo $image;?>" width="80" height="80"/>
    <?php
    $count++;
    print "</td>";
}
if($count>0)
   print "</tr>";
```

Otherwise it only loops the next direct line of code.

Comment: If i put if($image) it will show all of the pictures on one row, not 3 on a row how it supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have very bad logic at the `while`. You're saying `while $image exists` do the following. Well `$image` doesn't change, which would cause the `while` to continue forever. The end most likely comes when the script reaches the `max_execution_time`.

Your current code is designed to repeat images. If you do not wish to do this, you must remove the `while` loop in the `foreach`.

Also take note that since you do not have braces, ONLY the `while` will execute in the `foreach` and the `if` statement will be executed once when it is done. If not repeating, use braces for the `foreach` to ensure everything is running when you want it to.

As such:

```
foreach(glob("images/{*.gif,*.jpg,*.png,*.jpeg,*.bmp}", GLOB_BRACE) as $image)
{
        if($count==3)
        {
           print "</tr>";
           $count = 0;
        }
        if($count==0)
           print "<tr>";
        print "<td>";
        ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $image;?>" width="80" height="80"/>
        <?php
        $count++;
        print "</td>";
}
if($count > 0)
    print "</tr>";
```